# What is probability that $W_1<W_2$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(W)$ be s standard Wiener process. What is $\mathbb{P}(W_1<W_2)$? I Think it is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ but I can't explain it. Anyone?

Comment: Hint: Do you know the distribution of $W_2-W_1$?

Comment: $W_2-W_1$~$N(0,2-1)$

Comment: And $P(W_2>W_1)=P(W_2-W_1>0)=\ldots$?

Comment: obviously $1/2$

Comment: Now, post your thoughts as an answer and accept it. That way, other users might find this question helpful and at the same time, it won't appear in the "unanswered" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $W$ is a Wiener process, we know that $W_2-W_1$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. Hence, $P(W_2>W_1)=P(W_2-W_1>0)=1/2$, because the PDF of $N(0,1)$ is symmetrical.